# What is the recommended EC2 instance size for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We plan to use MongoDB in production for our website which will be hosted (for the start) on a single ec2 instance.
What is the recommandation for a MongoDB, which will have around 25k documents for the start with low traffic? So far i am not used to AWS, therefore a have no comparison to other dedicated hosters.

The "storagesize" of the collection in question will be arond 400MB, "totalindexsize" maybe around 20MB

Comment: The best thing for you to do is benchmark, as there is no "right" answer to this. It will be heavily dependent on your content and query patterns+frequency.

Answer (score 6):

If it's not a production instance, you can start with t2.medium instance. If its a production instance, start with m5.large.

Attach a new ebs volume of size 10GB and configure mongodb to use this new volume as the data directory. This helps to scale up your storage easily at later point of time.

Make sure you format your ebs volume to have xfs file system before installing mongodb which is required for best performance by mongo.

Also, later if you feel like increasing the instace size wheb your traffic increases, just use the "instance modify" option to get it done.

Comment: m5.large is indeed a good choice for starters. EBS optimized + high networking speed seals the deal

Answer (score 2):

I cannot give you a specific answer, but the cloud provides you with the option to test your setup very quickly. Just start with some instance (e.g. m3.medium) and you can create an Amazon Machine Image of your running MongoDB instance anytime and just start it on a larger or smaller instance type.

You can find the instance types here: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

Deeper thought about the instance type choice can be found here: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/maximizing-mongodb-performance-on-aws

> If you have any doubt about sizing, err on the side of going larger and then scaling down as needed. Undersizing your instances when deploying MongoDB can, and likely will, create performance problems. In order to achieve the best performance, your MongoDB working set should fit in memory.
>
> The working set is the portion of data and related indexes that your clients access most frequently.